# Best way to move sprites in OpenGL - translate or alter vertices

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

I am creating an app for android using openGL ES. I am trying to draw, in 2D, lots of moving sprites which bounce around the screen.

Let's consider I have a ball at coordinates 100,100. The ball graphic is 10px wide, therefore I can create the vertices `boundingBox = {100,110,0, 110,110,0, 100,100,0, 110,100,0}` and perform the following on each loop of `onDrawFrame()` with the ball texture loaded.

```
//for each ball object
FloatBuffer ballVertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
ballVertexBuffer.put(ball.boundingBox);
ballVertexBuffer.position(0);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, ballVertexBuffer); 
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,4);
```

I would then update the `boundingBox` array to move the balls around the screen.

Alternatively, I could not alter the `bounding box` at all and instead `translatef()` the ball before drawing the verticies

```
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, ballVertexBuffer); 
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(ball.posX, ball.posY, 0);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,4);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

What would be the best thing to do in the case in terms of efficient and best practices.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL ES (as of 2.0) does **not** support instancing, unluckily. If it did, I would recommend drawing a 2-triangle sprite instanced *N* times, reading the x/y offsets of the center point, and possibly a scale value if you need differently sized sprites, from a vertex texture (which ES supports just fine). This would limit the amount of data you must push per frame to a minimum.

Assuming you can't do the simulation directly on the GPU (thus avoiding uploading the vertex data each frame) ... this basically leaves you only with only one efficient option:
Generate 2 VBOs, map one and fill it, while the other is used as the source of the draw call. You can also do this *seemingly* with a single buffer if you `glBufferData(... 0)` in between, which tells OpenGL to generate a new buffer and throw the old one away as soon as it's done reading from it.

Streaming vertices in every frame may not be super fast, but this does not matter as long as the latency can be well-hidden (e.g. by drawing from one buffer while filling another). Few draw calls, few state changes, and ideally no stalls should still make this fast.

Comment: I must admit that I have only started openGL yesterday. I cannot make full sense of your answer right now. Are you suggesting that the program can be optimized, as filling a VBO and drawing a VBO can be done concurrently on different pieces of hardware?

Comment: A buffer object is an abstraction of "some memory" that you don't own (except when you do). The OpenGL implementation (or the GPU) can thus read data from it knowing that the data is well-defined and valid. When you map the buffer to write to it, or while glBufferData is running, this is not the case. Data is changing. Therefore, OpenGL must obviously block you until it's done reading data, and it can only start reading once you have unmapped the buffer or glBufferData has finished. However, if you call BufferData(0), you tell OpenGL that you are not really interested ...

Comment: ... in this buffer any more, but you want a new one to write to. Which you promptly get, too (without any observeable difference). This also marks the current buffer as deleted, and OpenGL will eventually delete it -- but only after it does not need to read from it any more. Which means no more and no less than a) you don't need wait for drawing to finish, and b) drawing does not need to wait for you. This avoids the pipeline from stalling.

Comment: I think I need some sleep before I can digest. Thank you for the help man, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing calls are much more expensive than altering the data. Also glTranslate is not nearly as efficient as just adding a few numbers, after all it has to go through a full 4×4 matrix multiplication, which is 64 scalar multiplies and 16 scalar additions.

Of course the best method is using some form of instancing.

Comment: what about if I were to keep a copy of the `ballVertexBuffer`. I wouldn't have to load the vertices into a VBO on every call if I used translate

Comment: I have read something which seems to suggest that glTranslate will be a better option http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8658/opengl-es-2-0-using-vbos . Bearing in mind Matrix multiplication is the bread and butter of a GPU - perhaps it is best to translate? That said, I'm not sure how many phones have GPUs

Comment: @user1093404 But `glTranslate` is not executed on the GPU. datenwolf refers to the `glTranslate` call, which multiplies the current modelview matrix with a translation matrix. This has nothing to do with the multiplication of each vertex by the modelview matrix, which is always done (assuming you don't use shaders) and always on GPU, no matter what technique you use. But the `glTranslate` call does a single matrix multiply, but on the CPU.

Comment: @user1093404 The question you refer to is of a completely different nature and is concerned about larger objects, for which a transformation is also not that easy as a simple translation and is a bit misinformed anyway. This is a different than your many simple and equal 4-vertex objects.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the input Christian. So if for example I had an object with many thousands of vertices, then it might be better do it the other way, but it's not worth it in my case?

Comment: @user1093404 The thing is also that when you have rather large objects, you also tend to have fewer of them and not thousands. Though if you had then techniques like instancing come into play, but you wouldn't just update the vertices manually. But in your case you have many many similar very small objects, whose individual vertices can be updated very fast by hand/CPU and this might be faster than invocing a single draw call for each small quad (which somehow nukes the purpose of VBOs or vertex arrays in general). And like said, this `glTranslate` call also doesn't come for free.

Comment: @user1093404 It's just that for larger objects the drawcall overhead and the CPU matrix manipulation overhead becomes much more insignificant, whereas the manual CPU-based vertex update becomes much more expensive and can be done by the GPU much faster.

Comment: @user1093404: So far you're using ols style Vertex Arrays, not VBOs yet.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm not am I. Terribly sorry

Comment: @user1093404: No need to be sorry. Actually in your specific case a traditional Vertex Array may perform better than a VBO.